# Воспрять или воспрянуть?

Tags: грамотная-речь

***Он воспрял (они воспряли) духом*** или ***он воспрянул (они воспрянули) духом***?
Довольно часто можно услышать первый вариант.

Comment: возможно воспрянуть связан с восперить восперять http://www.feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/03/sl408306.htm?cmd=p&istext=1 и сониа вперяютъ безумныа

Comment: в старославянском три глагола, например, порочити порицати и порещи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспрять - скорей всего это окказиональный глагол, его нет ни в одном толковом словаре, даже в ушаковском.Только один нормативный глагол - воспрянуть. Тем не менее выражение  "Воспрять духом" уже закрепилось в речи и используется в литературе. 
Поиск по блогам выдает на запросы: Воспрял/воспряла/воспряли/воспряло 12753 авторов блогов
)воспрянул | !воспрянула | !воспрянули | !воспрянуло 6497 авторов блогов